# Issue when installing pod library with my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, cocoapods

I am using several the Parse SDK in my application, the application runs smoothly. However, I am using pods in my app for the first time, I have been able to successfully setup and install cocoa pods in my project... i run the command `pod install` and when I do that, I get 4 red Xcode warnings, totally unrelated to cocoa pods .. an Apple Match-O Linker Error that seems to be coming from a Twitter service handled by Parse... (odd, considering I am not doing anything with Twitter in my project although I am working with Facebook login)... 
[image]

Anyway, I "clean" the project and the 4 red warnings go away, I then build and boom, they are back! :S

This is a problem that happens ONLY when I `pod install` and after, closing Xcode and coming back in does not fix the problem... can someone tell me what is going on here? Or how I can resolve this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem by adding the "Social.framework" to my project.